# In-built potential of the pn-junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I was reading today about the pn junction and there are two things that I don't understand or rather I have no knowledge about.

The first is to know whether the CB of the p-doped semiconductor has higher energy value than the CB of the n-doped semiconductor?

And second, in the lecture the claim was made that the energy difference between the two CBs of the two regions (p-doped semiconductor and n-doped one) is equal to $eU_{in}$. Under which bases we make this claim? How do we come up with this claim, how can we know that that's the case?

All I know is that because of the movement of electrons from the n-doped region to the p-doped one and the opposite movement of the holes, both of these processes (diffusion of charged carriers/diffusion current), a positive charged is generated in the n-doped region and a negative one in the p-doped one. As a result a potential field with direction from $n$ to $p$ is created, which causes the drift current (of either electrons or holes). I understand that the value of this in-built potential depends on the concentration of charged carriers. But I don't understand how do we come up with the claim that the difference in energy between the two Conductive Bands (CB) is equal to $eU_{bi}$

Answer (score 0):

> The first is to know whether the CB of the p-doped semiconductor has higher energy value than the CB of the n-doped semiconductor?

As you probably know, what you are asking is the doping dependency of electron affinity of semiconductors, because affinity is the energy difference between the conduction band minimum (CBM) to the vacuum energy level. I am not a material expert, but I believe doping concentration will surely influence the electron affinity.

> And second, in the lecture the claim was made that the energy difference between the two CBs of the two regions (p-doped semiconductor and n-doped one) is equal to $eU_{in}$. Under which bases we make this claim? How do we come up with this claim, how can we know that that's the case?

I think this is the definition is $eU_{in}$, the energy difference between two CBs of the two regions. Note that, in compositionally-graded layers, such as In$_x$Ga$_{1-x}$As, the electron affinity may be position-dependent, so the built-in potential $U_in$ is not equal to the energy difference between vacuum levels of those two regions.